# Searching each element of array using like

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like some professional advice regarding my problem.

You see our database is using an ETL to retrieve massive data. Some or rather most of these data are aggregated.

Problem is I need to retrieve a data, base on the selected Stations

For example. I selected `MNL`.

Now, in aggregated column we have arrays like:

```
{MNL-CEB,CEB-MNL,DVO-MNL,MNL-DVO,DVO-CEB,CEB-DVO}
```

Now, given with my selected code (MNL), I should only be able to pick the following elements from the array.

```
MNL-CEB,
CEB-MNL,
DVO-MNL,
MNL-DVO
```

I've been trying various where conditions with no success. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Here's a piece of code I've been using below -

```
select distinct
    unnest(fpd.segment_agg) segments
 from daylightreport.f_dailysales_agg fpd
```

The data is too big to unnest, causing the script to load more.

**Edit** - I'm also using more than 1 station code. For instance
`Where fpd.segment_agg IN ('MNL','CEB')` or something similar to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need all those values them as separate rows? If yes, why did you store them in an array in the first place? With a properly normalized model this would be very easy. Or is it OK to just return an array with those values for each row?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reponse. My boss is the one who created the data warehouse. I'm guessing the aggregated set is due to the summation of total amount of all of those stations. Anyway, no, I don't necessarily need all of them. I just need the stations that contains the station that I filtered in the parameter. I'll talk to my boss regarding the normalization. :)

Comment: if you need some elements from array - you either know the index or unnest is UNAVOIDABLE. to build new array based on old array values you NEED to unnest the array - right? what you mean by "data is too big to unnest, causing the script to load more."?..

Comment: Hi Vao. Thanks for your response.

Each person could have multiple stations. If I unnest them first it could mean extracting ALL stations instead of selecting those who are just needed.

So far. This is the code I'm using.

`select
 segments
from
(
select distinct
 unnest(fpd.segment_agg) segments
from daylightreport.f_dailysales_agg fpd
)segs
where substring(segments from '...$') IN ('MNL','CEB')`

It's slow because it is unnesting the array first before filtering it with only what the user wanted to see. Whereas, my idea is to filter it BEFORE the unnesting. :( no luck

Comment: Since you are not looking exact element value in the array then you can not *prefilter* before unnesting. With the way you want to find the data right now, you have to unnest either within junks using [LATERAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join or subquery (as you currently do). Or as suggested, normalise the data to ease the task. In case you can search by exact array element values then using [array operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html) `@>` and index can help to speed up the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that avoids unnesting is to convert the array to a string then do a regex match on that string:

```
select *
from daylightreport.f_dailysales_agg fpd
where array_to_string(fpd.segment_agg, ',') ~ '(-){0,1}(MNL)(-){0,1}';
```

The regex makes sure the search string doesn't appear as part of another string. If that can't happen anyway, a simple like would probably do as well. This also assumes that the data never contains a `,`

This is **not** going to be fast though, but avoids the unnesting in multiple rows.

Another option (although probably not really that much faster) is to write a function that loops through the array elements and uses the LIKE operator:

```
create or replace function any_element_like(p_elements text[], p_pattern text)
  returns boolean
as
$$
declare
   l_word text;
begin
  foreach l_word in array p_elements 
  loop
    if l_word like p_pattern then 
      return true;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return false;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

That could be used like this:

```
select *
from daylightreport.f_dailysales_agg fpd
where any_element_like(fpd.segment_agg, '%MNL%');
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this!

This is much better than my subquery. However, what if I want to use two or more stations? would be it possible to make the regex dynamic? instead of one station only? :)